# System requirements for Ubuntu installation

Tags: system-requirements

I am new to ubuntu. I am having a PC with Pentium 4 processor 512 MB ram and an  inbuilt graphics card. Can I install Ubuntu on my system? Right now I am having Windows XP. But it is somehow corrupted. Please help. How can I install Ubuntu on my system? Will it work fine with my system specifications?

Comment: you can use an old version of ubuntu 32bit edition but I wouldn't recommend it.  I just tried to revive one with a much faster processor and separate dedicated graphics added raid to it...and its just miserable.  I think its time to get a new one.  Or experiment with the variants that are designed to run on burner phones...maybe that will work

Comment: I suggest trying lubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You can run it but if I were you I would upgrade that! For that PC, it would be best to put a Lubuntu version on which will be much lighter and faster!

**Lowest Specs: Ubuntu Desktop Edition**

700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
512 MiB RAM (system memory)
5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)